# Запутался с флагами, ARM

Tags: c#, arm

Доброго времени суток. Что-то я уже мозг сломал. Нужно реализовать на С#, то что происходит в контроллере.

```
CMP     R0, R3
BLE     loc_7BAE    ; я так понимаю, знаковое сравнение. (Z==1) || (N!=V)
. . . 
loc_7BAE:
ADDS    R4, R0, #0  ; а вот тут, у нас в каких случаях будет +1???
```

Ну то есть, на шарпе получаем так? или не совсем так?

```
if (R0 <= R3) // R0, R3 - Int32
{
    R4 = R0;           // R4 = R0 + 0
    if(R0 == R3) R4++; // ???

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница в том, что команда `ADD` не обновляет флаги, а `ADDS` - обновляет в зависимости от результата сложения. Поэтому +1 у вас уже точно не будет, но если дальше есть какие-то `BXX`- проверки, надо посмотреть внимательнее.

Подробнее: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489i/Cihcjfjg.html

Взято здесь: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/4262

Comment: Да спасибо. Вчера ночью разобрался (тупо доделал модель и прокрутил. и понял что там +0, иначе не выходит из цикла). Просто это место посещается из двух разных условий (там без goto на язык высокого уровня не раскладывается. видимо оптимизация какая-то. )и вот во-втором случае, как раз всегда +1 получается. У меня тупо дважды это место в модели. в разных условиях поставлено.

Answer (score 0):

Вот как это выглядело (может кому пригодится)

```
00007B98            CMP             R4, R3
00007B9A            BLE             loc_7BAA
00007B9C            CMP             R0, R3
00007B9E            BLE             loc_7BAE
00007BA0            MOVS            R3, #8
00007BA2            SUBS            R4, R3, R2
00007BA4            LSLS            R4, R4, #0x10
00007BA6            LSRS            R4, R4, #0x10
00007BA8            B               loc_7BB0
00007BAA
00007BAA loc_7BAA:
00007BAA            CMP             R4, R0
00007BAC            BLS             loc_7BB0
00007BAE
00007BAE loc_7BAE:
00007BAE            ADDS            R4, R0, #0
00007BB0
00007BB0 loc_7BB0:
```

на шарпе получилось так:

```
bool cmp_le(uint r1, uint r2)
{  // для имитации ble приводим сравниваемые к знаковым значениям и сравниваем
   int i1 = (int)r1;
   int i2 = (int)r2;
   return (i1 <= i2);
}

if (!cmp_le(R4, R3))
{
    if (cmp_le(R0, R3))
    {
        R4 = R0;// adds r0,0 но ble => z=1 || n != v 
    }
    else
    {
        R4 = (8 - R2) & 0xFFFF;
    }
}
else if (R4 > R0)
{
     R4 = R0 + 1; // ?? adds r0,0 но bhi => z=0, c=1 
}
```